# Using Fillo How to read all the rows?

Tags: java, excel, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

Using fillo i have managed to read the data for a Specific Test-case using fillo. But i have requirement saying need to be executed multiple test cases at a time. so according to the requirement to read all rows and store in hash-map as a key value pair.

Down i will attach my code which i wrote to read a specific test-case and putted in hash-map.

```
public HashMap<String, String> extractexcelData(String TestcaseID, String sheetname) throws Exception
    {
        HashMap<String, String> excelhashmapvalues = new HashMap<String, String>();
        Connection connect = fillo.getConnection("src/test/resources/Datatable/MasterTestdata.xlsx");
        String query = " Select * from " + sheetname + " where TestcaseID='" + TestcaseID + "'";
        Recordset recordset = connect.executeQuery(query);
        while(recordset.next())
        {
            ArrayList<String> collection = recordset.getFieldNames();
            int size = collection.size();
            for (i = 0; i <=(size-1); i++) {
                String colname = collection.get(i);
                String colval = recordset.getField(colname);
                excelhashmapvalues.put(colname, colval);

            }

        }

        recordset.close();
        connect.close();
        return excelhashmapvalues;
    }
```

My Excel format is,

[image]

you can see right i have 8 testcases i need to read all eight testcases and put it into hashmap .Help required!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that when you process the next record set, you overwrite the values in the map, because you have the same column names.

The solution may be to keep your data in the list of maps:

```
List<Map<String, String>> listOfMaps = new ArrayList<>();
while(recordset.next()) {
    ArrayList<String> collection = recordset.getFieldNames();
    int size = collection.size();
    Map<String, String> values = new HashMap<>();
    for (i = 0; i <=(size-1); i++) {
        String colname = collection.get(i);
        String colval = recordset.getField(colname);
        values.put(colname, colval);
    }
    listOfMaps.add(values);
}
```

Or keep it in the map of value lists by column name:

```
Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
while(recordset.next()) {
    ArrayList<String> collection = recordset.getFieldNames();
    int size = collection.size();
    for (i = 0; i <=(size-1); i++) {
        String colname = collection.get(i);
        String colval = recordset.getField(colname);
        map.computeIfAbsent(colname, k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(colval);
    }
}
```